# Different Result in Mysql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure named `getvotes(postitem varchar(50),userid varchar(50))` that gets the number of votes given by a user for certain item. The DML statement inside this procedure is

`` select count(*) from tblvotes where `postitem`=postitem and `userid`=userid; ``

it gives me the result of 30. But when I run the sql(outside the stored procedure with the same argument values) using

`` select count(*) from tblvotes where `postitem`=md5(1) and `userid`=md5(1); ``

the result is 10.

Whats wrong with my query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use parameter names that have the same name as column names or whatever.

I usually prefix every parameter with `p_` and every variable with `v_` to avoid such errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the encryption used for MD5 and User HEX if the hash comparison may fail

`select count(*) from tblvotes where`postitem`= HEX(MD5(1) and`userid`= HEX(MD5(1));`